# UIMenuController is getting dismissed immediately after being presented

Tags: ios, uikit, ios9, uimenucontroller

I have subclassed UIWebView to add custom UIMenuController functionality in and it was working pretty well up until iOS 9. I am not sure what has changed, but now I am running into a situation where when I tap on a link, that should present the menu, the menu shows up briefly, but is dismissed (with no more tapping from me).

I am having a hard time figuring out where that dismissal is originating from. I am observing the `UIMenuControllerDidHideMenuNotification` notification, and that is indeed being called right after the menu disappears, but I am having a hard time finding the cause of the dismissal.

I recognize that there are many different issues that could be lurking, but I am wondering if anyone has experienced something like this before? Is there a way to track somehow the cause of the dismissal?

[image]

Comment: Maybe if you could post all the code related displaying/hiding the menu controller we could help more.

Comment: I think you need to show some code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue with iOS9, I think it happens as a result of multiple process. This isn't the ideal solution but... After I becomeFirstResponder I added a DELAY before the setMenuVisible:YES .

[self performSelector:@selector(showMenuController:) withObject:point afterDelay:0.4];

Comment: Worked great! I'll award the bounty as soon as it lets me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try by adding following method in your view controller.

```
- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder { 
   return YES; 
}
```

Comment: I should have clarified, I do have that in there.

Comment: I see. Are you also calling `-becomeFirstResponder` on the view or view controller?

Comment: Yeah, I am calling becomeFirstResponder before the menuController is supposed to be displayed. That is originating from the view, not the VC. Thanks for your help, btw.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar issue trying to display a UIMenuController inside a custom view. And the delay fix mentioned above did not work.

To fix it I had to add overrides to canBecomeFirstResponder so it returned true, to both my custom view AND the viewController it was contained in.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange; however, in my case I set label's UIFont to `.SFUIText-Light` and it lead the menuController dismiss automatically. The solution is to change the font to `SanFranciscoDisplay`.

Btw, I recommend you to use `git bisect` to debug which commit lead this error if you use git as your version control.